# Помогите математически решить задачу на C++, используя только целочисленное деление и остаток от деления

Tags: c++

Существует бесконечно высокий дом, в котором нумерация квартир начинается с единицы. Известен номер квартиры N. Определите на каком этаже находится данная квартира, если всего на этаже располагается по 12 квартир.

**Формат входных данных:**

Целое положительное число N не превосходящее 10^9

**Формат выходных данных:**

Целое число - номер этажа, на котором расположена квартира

Мой код:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    long int a;
    cin >> a;
    cout << (a / 12);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Суть заключается в том, что нужно использовать только остаток от деления и целочисленное деление, а у меня появляется проблема при N < 12. Если ввод, например, равен 10, то в ответе будет 0, а должно быть 1, но если я просто прибавлю 1, то при вводе 12 ответ будет 2, а не 1.

Comment: "а у меня появляется проблема при N < 12" - секретная?

Comment: Так "используя" или "не используя" деление?

Comment: @Harry Извините, уже исправил свой недочёт в вопросе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(a - 1) / 12 + 1
```

*(Тело сообщения должно содержать не менее 30 символов).*

Comment: Обычно сообщения длиннее 30 символов потому что включают объяснения как, что и почему.

Answer (score -1):

```
int a;
std::cin >> a;
std::cout << a / 12 + ((a % 12) > 0) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: В учебных целях требуется решить задачу используя только целочисленное деление и остаток от деления, без использования условий, так, как ранее показал пользователь Igor.

Comment: Зачем тут тернарный оператор? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Тернарный оператор тут - проверяет наличие остатка от деления. Если он есть, то квартира этажом выше. В ответе пользователя Igor - не используется оператор "остаток от деления", хотя в условии задачи его нужно использовать.

Comment: @Ярослав <чтобы пришло уведомление, ставьте собаку с ником> нет, сначала сработает `<<`, а потом проверка, на что я и намекнул ссылкой

Comment: dIm0n -> вы ошиблись, в данном контексте, тернарный оператор является правым параметром для оператора суммы и выполняется при его, operator+() вызове. Сумма имеет приоритет над сдвигом влево. Я обозначил приоритет вызова тернарного оператора (как правого параметра суммы) с помощью скобок.

Comment: @Ярослав <ещё раз, вы не поставили собаку и не было уведомления https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment> нет, вы скобки не там поставили, чтобы сделать то, что задумывается. Смотрите https://godbolt.org/z/r989bM

Comment: @dIm0n Всё работает: [https://godbolt.org/z/WqP5ff](https://godbolt.org/z/WqP5ff)

Comment: @Ярослав вы считаете, что `?` выполнится до `<<`? Если да, то почему мой пример компилируется?